Problems with the proof of theorem $3$ in section $5.3$ in Evans' PDE book
The following is theorem $3$ in section $5.3$ of Evans' PDE book:

Assume $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary. Suppose $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$ for some $1\leq p < \infty,$ then there exists functions $u_m\in C^\infty(\overline{U})$ such that $u_m\to u$ in $W^{k,p}(U)..$

The proof is formulated into five steps:
Step I: For each $x_0\in\partial U,$ pick $r>0$ such that after relabeling the coordinate there is a $C^1$ function $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}$ and
$$U\cap B_r(x_0)=B_r(x_0)\cap \{x_n>\gamma(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})\}$$
also set $V= U\cap B_{r/2}(x_0)$
Step II: For $x\in V,$ define shifted point the
$$x^\varepsilon = x + \lambda \varepsilon e_n $$
with some fixed $\lambda>0$ large enough so that $B_\varepsilon(x^\varepsilon)\subset U\cap B_r(x^0)$ for all $x\in V$ and all small $\varepsilon > 0.$
Define
$$u_\varepsilon(x)=u(x^\varepsilon),x\in V, \qquad v^\varepsilon = \eta_\varepsilon * u_\varepsilon$$
where $\eta_\varepsilon$ is the standard mollifier. It's easy to see that $v^\varepsilon\in C^\infty(\overline{V}).$
Step III: This is the step that confuses me. In the book he claims that
$$v^\varepsilon\to u  \qquad \text{in} ~W^{k,p}(V)$$
through the following inequality
$$\|D^\alpha v^\varepsilon-D^\alpha u\|_{L^p(V)}\leq \|D^\alpha v^\varepsilon- D^\alpha u_\varepsilon\|_{L^p(V)}+\|D^\alpha u_\varepsilon-D^\alpha u\|_{L^p(V)}$$
where the second term on the right goes to zero with $\varepsilon$ since translation is continuous in $L^p$ norm. But I don't know why the first term will also go to zero. After changing variables, I get
$$D^\alpha v^\varepsilon(x) =D^\alpha_x\int_V \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)u_\varepsilon(y)dy = (-1)^\alpha \int_{V+\lambda\varepsilon e_n}D_z^\alpha \eta_{\varepsilon}(x^\varepsilon-z)u(z)dz$$
it seems that I cannot switch the derivative on $\eta_\varepsilon$ to $u$ since $\eta_\varepsilon(x^\varepsilon-\cdot)$ does not have compact support in $V+\lambda\varepsilon e_n,$ so I am stuck. Can someone help me?
